# How to split the array and store into respected columns of table in Postgresql DataBase

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, phppgadmin

I am inserting the array of elements {idno,age,salary} as `{1,10000,30}`
in PostgreSQL database and I need to split and store into the respected columns of the table.

How to store the split array elements in respect columns of  table?

First is this possible , if possible can some one explain me ,how can we do it?

Comment: So you have an array containing those three numbers inside PostgreSQL and you want to `update ... set idno=1, age=10000, salary=30` on some table?

Comment: Thank you,i am inserting the array  of elements in respected columns on some table.and those three numbers inserted in their respected columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
insert into test(idno, age, salary)
select D[1], D[2], D[3]
from (select '{1,10000,30}'::int[]) as A(D);
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ebb5d/3)</kbd>**